# If condition on separated functions

Tags: javascript, function

Here is an example of what I like to do:

```
var example = {
    before: function() {
        `if (1 == 1) {`
    },
    after: function() {
        `}`
    }
};

example.before();
alert('Success!');
example.after();
```

I'd like to involve `alert('Success!')` by a `if (1 == 1)` condition under these circumstances.

Is it possible?

Comment: You really don't want to write code like this... if I came across a code base which attempted to use vague, nondescript, macro like functions to paste strings all over which come together to form executable code I would tear my hair out and quit.  Unless of course there is some sort of legitimate use for something like this which I can't think of.  However, your attempt will never work. You would need to call  `eval()` on a string which contains code, but legitimate uses for that are far and few between.

Comment: "I'd like to involve alert('Success!') by a if (1 == 1)" what does this line mean... you mean on condition if (1 == 1) is true at that time you want to show alert?. also if(1==1) this will always evaluate true.

Comment: @Jayesh: He's writing two functions which return the enclosing bits of an if statement as strings and thinking that, if he calls the functions *around* a piece of code, that text in the middle will be reinterpreted as code and  executed.

Comment: wooh! wooh! wooh! Don't do this. Is there **any** perceivable reason to do this?

Comment: ohhh... I thought this is just a snippet he posted to give an idea of what he want to achieve but if he mean what you told then I am not able to understand where such business scenario can come.....

Comment: Oh boy. That's enough internet for today.

Comment: Thanks! I'm working on a code that isn't mine, I also don't like this solution, buuut... Well, could you help me with the technical arguments why not do it?

Comment: @CaioTarifa: The technical argument is that it makes no sense.  The value returned from a function is not pasted into the code itself and interpreted.  Your code is compiled as is and executed.  Your two functions simply return `undefined` due to the missing `return` statements.  Also, your condition is always true, so... honestly, some time spent learning the basics would be well worth the effort.

Comment: The person who wrote this simply doesn't understand the basics of how programs are executed. He doesn't even have `return` statements in his functions!

Comment: The true condition was intentional, and the lack of return also. The above code was just an example. I'm working on "some code that generates code". Can you imagine? I'm freaking out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var example = {
    before: function() {
        return 'if (1 == 1) {';
    },
    after: function() {
        return '}';
    }
};

var code = example.before() + "alert('Success!');" + example.after();
eval(code);
```

But you should not go crazy like this in your production code if you are writing some regular stuff.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to fix this frankenstein. :)